# Доступ к сервису в рамках одного приложения docker (docker-compose)

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, docker-compose, lamp

**Предистория:**

Хочется организовать множество php приложений, используя docker. Получив возможность запускать несколько приложений одновременно, а доступ к ним был по адресам вида app1.work, app2.work (т.е. по именам без указания порта), а для создания нового приложения будет достаточно создать каталог и положить в него docker-compose.yml такой как и у других и файлик env.yml который в нем подключается отредактировав только файл с переменными окружения т.е. env.yml указав например только VIRTUAL_HOST для приложения.

**Схема:**
dns-masq, nginx-proxy (от Jason Wilder's как точка входа), приложения в контейнерах

Каждое приложение в основном apache+php, mysql, phpmyadmin.

**В чем проболема:**
Для того что nginx-proxy мог обращатся к приложениям, необходимо что бы они были подключены к общей сети c ним, и получается что если у нас файл docker-compose.yml одинаковый имена сервисов в нем одинаковые т.е. использование имени сервиса в качестве hostname в приложении не прокатит (например для подключения к БД) т.к. у на в одной сети будет несколько хостов с одинаковыми именами.

**Вопрос:**
Как можно обращаться между сервисами одного приложения чтобы это были точно его (приложения) сервисы без префиксирования собственно имен сервисов?

Comment: если вся проблема в hostname, то можно же воспользоваться явным указанием  hostname  и брать его из переменной окружения. Тут у вас скорее будет сложность запускать docker-compose файлы с одинаковым названием сервисов, для этого используйте ключ -p   при запуске.

Comment: А почему с запуском должны быть проблемы если docker-compose использует в качестве имени проекта название каталога, и сам префиксирует сервисы, при этом даже отслеживает дублирование и подставляет индекс и получаем названия контейнеров вида <projName>_<serviceName>_<index>, а вот про hostname в переменных окружения можно поподробнее, т.к. не нашел в доках возможности указать hostname для контейнера в docker-compose.yml

Comment: Ну да, в случае если вы описываете каждую связку сервисов отдельным docker-compose файлом, то вероятно все как вы говорите. Мне просто думается что возможно это не лучший вариант. Как минимум для каждого проекта вы будете иметь одинаковый файл с разными значениями. По факту это похоже на дублирование кода и в дальнейшем будет вызывать сложности в поддержке.

Comment: По поводу hostname тут я имел в виду  директиву container_name сделать и получить что вы желаете.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#container_name

Однако мне думается что более верный вариант описать aliases в секции networks , ведь у вас для сервисов общая сеть, по сему вы можете писать сколь угодно алисов для сколь угодно сетей и по факту получать доступ с разными именами.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#networks

Comment: Ну и последнее. Подумайте над вариантом описывать свои сервисы все же в одном docker-compose файле, если уж они все равно одинаковые. Плодить дублирующий код  хороша только сначала, потом это превращается в гемморой. 
Вы попросту создаете для каждого варианта сервиса свои .env переменные и запускаете один и тот же docker-compose просто с соответствующим файлом значений этих переменных. Там же можно и прописать условный "namespace" для запускаемых сервисов, чтоб они друг другу не мешали. Ну или некоторые вместо env файлов добавляют override файл со своими значениями.

Comment: ну на счет последнего варианта это хорошая идея, но вот только сейчас попробовал использовать переменную окружения COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME и параметр сервиса container_name что бы префиксировать имена сервисов но видимо docker не добавляет dns запись по container_name печалька... дублирование кода не сильно напрягает, т.к. в дальнейшем они будут оптимизироваться под каждый проект. Если в кратце ранее была схема dnsmasq + apache (vhosts) и получалось так, для создания нового проекта достаточно было создать 1 каталог и положить код туда, далее просто набрать project1.work где "project1" каталог.

Comment: вот теперь хочется такую же схему реализовать через docker, но схема чуть измениться, я сначала набираю project1.work (по первому запросу соответственно нечего показывать поэтому будет какая нибудь дефолтная страница с надписью "делаем магию") по которому будет создание каталога и закидывание docker-compose.yml по окончании процесса  как стартуют контейнеры, перекидываем на страничку типо все готово из самого каталога src|app проекта и предлагаем засунуть сорцы. Как-то так. Хотя можно и оригинальную схему реализовать, кидаем сорцы, а по первому запросу наводим марофет с контейнерами.